# Restrict content access based on intranet/Internet access

Tags: security, access, content

Hi Expert Sharepoint architectures,

Our IT director is inquiring about if it's possible to limit the content access based on the network access (intranet or Internet)? For example, user has full/normal access while on the intranet with upload/download/edit, but only has read access (no download/upload) while on the internet.

I can create a separate internal web application only for this, but the content will probably have to be maintained twice. He didn't specifically say the reason but I think this is designed so our sensitive information won't get uploaded to the public site by the employees.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, I don't recommend going this route because there are no easy ways of implementing it. And whatever option you choose - it will be extra maintenance work that could be spent doing something more useful.

But you can research the following options:

- Create a separate web application and setup daily syncrhonization process using Sharegate. Just make sure you copy only content with no permissions. The second web application we will have read-only permissions setup.
- Content Deployment. [See article by Stefan Gosner](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2009/10/30/content-deployment-the-complete-guide-part-1-the-basics/). I am not a fan of this feature and strongly recommend avoiding it, but I put it here just because someone will mention it.
- Protect your documents using [Azure Rights Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/what-is-azure-rms).

Comment: Thank you Denis for the feedback! Let me research into the options you provided. On the high level I think I agree with you not to waste too much effort on this kind of setup when SP already provided the user-based permission access so we can catch the culprit if needed. I think the director just does not want to see anything leaked out from IT-owned system whatsoever. Much appreciated!